# naming x axis on barplot in R

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to draw a barplot in R 
I have 2 vectors

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
y <- c(200,400,4000,255)

A <- rbind(x,y) # to make it into a matrix

barplot(A, ylim= c(0,5000))
```

I want to put at the base of each plot 1,2,3,4 on the x axis.

How can I do that

Thanks

Comment: Use `barplot(setNames(y,x))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
barplot(A, ylim= c(0,5000),names.arg=1:4)
```

This is how you do it.

My suggestion is that you should check the help manual/doc for each function carefully. R graphic functions usually have lots of arguments for various purposes.

Function "barplot" returns the x-axis value where each bar is centred. We can use these values as a reference to add legend on top of each bar, or any where else (but less straightforward).

To add on the top

```
x.axis <-barplot(A, ylim= c(0,5000),names.arg=1:4)
text(x.axis, y, adj = c(0.5, 0))  ## you have defined "y"
```